# I don't know why my footer is not 100% wide with bootstrap 4.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My footer is not getting 100% wide and i really don't know what is wrong. Maybe there's a problem with container nesting, but i don't know how to fix it properly. I've just started learning Bootstrap, so this is my first code with it.

```
 <div class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-around">
    <footer class="container-fluid align-items-center text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li class="mb-2 font-weight-bolder">Links</li>
            <li class="mb-2"><a class="text-reset" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="mb-2"><a class="text-reset" href="#">Cardápio</a></li>
            <li class="mb-2"><a class="text-reset" href="#">Contato</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li class="mb-2 font-weight-bolder">Pizzas</li>
            <li class="mb-2"><a class="text-reset" href="#">Tradicionais</a></li>
            <li class="mb-2"><a class="text-reset" href="#">Nobres</a></li>
            <li class="mb-2"><a class="text-reset" href="#">Doces</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="align-items-center">Pizzaria.com.br</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

[Here is the website print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4B4Y.png)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your .css file

```
body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it didn't worked :(, but thanks anyway!